# Google Geocoding API

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoder

It seems to be a Google bug. Consider the response from Google to this geocoding call:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=37.4242731%2C-122.1454809&sensor=true

The coordinate is in Palo Alto, which you can confirm using google map. The response from Google gives me the right street name and street number, even right county, but puts me 40 miles away in South San Francisco. Any ideas why?

Comment: How are you determining where that result is located?

Comment: I used first address component of response. It is simply incorrect, you can see following geocoding link above. What's interesting, it gives correct building number and street and county, but wrong city that happens to be in the different county. All in one address component.

Answer (score 0):

The place that gives me is in South San Francisco, only a 1.5 mile drive from Palo Alto:

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=37.4242731%2C-122.1454809&geocode=1&addr2=Palo%20Alto,CA&geocode=2

Comment: Yes, but in reality both places are in Palo Alto, tens of miles away from South San Francisco. I know that because I live here, but you can search for South San Francisco on Google Map to see how far it it is.

Comment: Probably need to [open an issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/) against the geocoder then.